# Javascript: is the Windows object a default object?

Tags: javascript, object, window, default-value

First time poster.  I tried to search for answer before posting.

I'm new to javascript, coming from a Delphi/pascal background.  I am used to things having to be explicitly spelled out.  When I see code that includes setTimeout or setInterval (see here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval1), I notice that it just looks like an intrinsic function.  But I think it is actually a method of the Windows object.

So it looks like the "window." part is optional.  Is this somethign specific to the Window object?  Or will any method that is specified without the name of it's containing object be recognized in javascript?  And what would happen if there was another variable in the global scope that had a method also named setTimeout?  How would the compiler/interpreter know which one to use?

Thanks so much,

Kevin

Comment: It's not the window per se, it's the scope you're in.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5

Comment: @Quentin: I tried to read your link.  Is ecmaScript(r) related to javascript??

Comment: @adeneo: so if I'm in scope, then containing object for any function is optional?

Comment: @kdtop "JavaScript" is a [trademarked name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Trademark) of the Oracle/Netscape/Mozilla *implementation/usage* of ECMAScript - but the terms are often used interchangeably and without much discretion to official trademarks.

Comment: @kdtop - Yes, but don't confuse it with dot notation in literals etc. The setInterval function is declared in the highest scope, window, so it's available in all scopes below, just like any variable, unless you declare a variable with the same name in a lower scope etc. It's really just variable scope, at least that's how I think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, there is something called the Global scope. On Browsers, the global scope object is `window`. If you create a variable outside of a function, it goes by default into the global scope, which is window.

When invoking a method or referencing a variable on the window object, it's optional to include `window`.

Comment: Thanks!  From what others have said, I think it is optional on any object, not just the window object.  Not sure I like all this laxness.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

its not windows its window (no 's' at end).
As far as i know javascript have 3 scopes local, [clouser], global

Every variable or function is first looked up in local scope, then clouser and finally if not found anywhere in between it will checked in global scope.

As in image you will see global scope is shown as Window object which mean whatever goes in global scope goes in window object.

copy paste below code in chrome devtools console

```
function outerFunction() { 
   var a = 10; 
   debugger; 
   function innerFunction() {
      'use strict'; 
      var b = 10;
      debugger; 
      console.log(a);
   } 
   innerFunction();
}
outerFunction();
```

on 1st debug 
[image: on 1st debug]

on 2nd debug
[image: on 2nd debug]